# Matching an integer to an array to grab the value?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure what it's called but after all the math is complete it'll return a value  between 0 and 11, I need to match that number to my zodAnimal and zodAnimalD corresponding to their position (so 0 would return rat, and the first description etc).

How do I do this?:

```
var birthYear = parseInt(prompt ('Enter your birth year:'));
var birthMonth = prompt ('Enter the name of the month of birth:');
var birthDay = parseInt(prompt ('Enter your day of birth as an integer:'));
var milliDay = 1000*60*60*24; //Milliseconds in a day
monthAbb = 'janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec';
chineseZod = 12;
zodCycle = 1924; //Chinese Zodiac Cycle
var zodAnimal = new Array('Rat','Ox','Tiger','Rabbit','Dragon','Snake','Horse','Goat','Monkey','Rooster','Dog','Pig');
var zodAnimalD = new Array('Forthright, tenacious, intense, meticulous, charismatic, sensitive, intellectual, industrious, charming, eloquent, sociable, artistic, and shrewd.  Can be manipulative, vindictive, self-destructive, envious, mendacious, venal, obstinate, critical, over-ambitious, ruthless, intolerant, and scheming.','Dependable, ambitious, calm, methodical, born leader, patient, hardworking, conventional, steady, modest, logical, resolute, and tenacious.  Can be stubborn, dogmatic, hot-tempered, narrow-minded, materialistic, rigid, and demanding.','Unpredictable, rebellious, colorful, powerful, passionate, daring, impulsive, vigorous, stimulating, sincere, affectionate, humanitarian, and generous.  Can be restless, reckless, impatient, quick-tempered, obstinate, selfish, aggressive, and moody.','Gracious, good friend, kind, sensitive, soft-spoken, amiable, elegant, reserved, cautious, artistic, thorough, tender, self-assured, shy, astute, compassionate, lucky, and flexible.  Can be moody, detached, superficial, self-indulgent, opportunistic, and stubborn.','Magnanimous, stately, vigorous, strong, self-assured, proud, noble, direct, dignified, eccentric, intellectual, fiery, passionate, decisive, pioneering, artistic, generous, and loyal.  Can be tactless, arrogant, imperious, tyrannical, demanding, intolerant, dogmatic, violent, impetuous, and brash.','Deep thinker, wise, mystic, graceful, soft-spoken, sensual, creative, prudent, shrewd, elegant, cautious, responsible, calm, strong, constant, and purposeful.  Can be a loner, bad communicator, possessive, hedonistic, self-doubting, distrustful, mendacious, suffocating, and cold.','Cheerful, popular, quick-witted, changeable, earthy, perceptive, talkative, agile, magnetic, intelligent, astute, flexible, and open-minded.  Can be fickle, arrogant, childish, anxious, rude, gullible, and stubborn.','Righteous, sincere, sympathetic, mild-mannered, observant, artistic, intellectual, ingenious, innovative, creative, mothering, peaceful, and generous.  Can be indecisive, over-passive, worrier, pessimistic, sensitive, shy, and weak-willed.','Inventor, motivator, improviser, quick-witted, inquisitive, flexible, innovative, problem solver, self-assured, sociable, artistic, polite, dignified, competitive, objective, and factual.  Can be egotistical, vain, arrogant, selfish, reckless, snobbish, deceptive, manipulative, cunning, jealous, suspicious, and stubborn.','  Acute, neat, meticulous, organized, self-assured, decisive, conservative, critical, perfectionist, alert, zealous, practical, scientific, and responsible.  Can be over zealous and critical, puritanical, egotistical, abrasive, proud, opinionated, and gives into empty bravado.','Honest, intelligent, straightforward, loyal, sense of justice and fair play, attractive, amicable, unpretentious, sociable, open-minded, idealistic, moralistic, practical, affectionate, sensitive, and easy going.  Can be cynical, lazy, cold, judgmental, pessimistic, worrier, stubborn, and quarrelsome.','Honest, gallant, sturdy, sociable, peace-loving, patient, loyal, hard-working, trusting, sincere, calm, understanding, thoughtful, scrupulous, passionate, and intelligent.  Can be naive, over-reliant, self-indulgent, gullible, fatalistic, and materialistic.');

var monthArr = new Array(11);

monthArr [0] = "jan";
monthArr [1] = "feb";
monthArr [2] = "mar";
monthArr [3] = "apr";
monthArr [4] = "may";
monthArr [5] = "jun";
monthArr [6] = "jul";
monthArr [7] = "aug";
monthArr [8] = "sep";
monthArr [9] = "oct";
monthArr [10] = "nov";
monthArr [11] = "dec";

var monthNum = monthAbb.indexOf(birthMonth.slice(0, 3).toLowerCase()) / 3;
alert(monthNum);
var d = new Date (birthYear, monthNum, birthDay);
alert(d);
var dCurrent = new Date();
dCurrent = dCurrent.getTime(); //Grabs the time of the current date in milliseconds.
d = d.getTime(); //Grabs the time of the user-entered date in milliseconds.
var dTotal = dCurrent - d;
alert(dTotal);
dTotal = dTotal / milliDay;
dTotal = Math.floor(dTotal); //7193
alert(dTotal + ' is after division');
dTotal = dTotal / 365.25;
dTotal = Math.floor(dTotal);
alert(dTotal + ' is how old you are!');
dTotal = birthYear - zodCycle;
dTotal = dTotal % chineseZod;
alert(dTotal);
```

Comment: zodAnimal[0] will return "rat".. is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to write to the page the corresponding entry to what they've put into the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply `zodAnimal[dTotal]` or `zodAnimalD[dTotal]`

```
alert(zodAnimal[dTotal]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
console.log(zodAnimal[dTotal]);
console.log(zodAnimalD[dTotal]);
```

Comment: I need to use document.write but I think what you've written might be what I'm looking for, I just can't use console.log.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write it to the page, there are two ways:

1. You could just do `document.write(zodAnimal[dTotal])`. However, this is a very crude way of doing it, and it erases everything in the document and writes what you want.
2. The other way is to create an HTML element:

Now, you just need to fill in the `<div>` with the data in `zodAnimal`, like this:

```
var placeholder = document.getElementById("zodText");
placeholder.innerHTML = zodAnimal[dTotal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way I might do this. I'd avoid things like 1000*60*60*24 for a start, since that's a constant (the number of seconds in a day doesn't change, so don't calculate it).

```
<html>
<body>

<label for='year'>Year:</label><input type='text' id='year' maxlength='4' size='4' />
<label for='month'>Month:</label><input type='text' id='month' maxlength='2' size='2'/>
<label for='day'>Day:</label><input type='text' id='day' maxlength='2' size='2' />
<input type='button' onclick='calc()' value='Calculate' />
<div id='result'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function val(el) {
    return document.getElementById(el).value;
}

function calc() {
        var data = [
            ['Rat','Forthright, tenacious, intense, meticulous, charismatic, sensitive, intellectual, industrious, charming, eloquent, sociable, artistic, and shrewd.  Can be manipulative, vindictive, self-destructive, envious, mendacious, venal, obstinate, critical, over-ambitious, ruthless, intolerant, and scheming.'],
            ['Ox','Dependable, ambitious, calm, methodical, born leader, patient, hardworking, conventional, steady, modest, logical, resolute, and tenacious.  Can be stubborn, dogmatic, hot-tempered, narrow-minded, materialistic, rigid, and demanding.'],
            ['Tiger','Unpredictable, rebellious, colorful, powerful, passionate, daring, impulsive, vigorous, stimulating, sincere, affectionate, humanitarian, and generous.  Can be restless, reckless, impatient, quick-tempered, obstinate, selfish, aggressive, and moody.'],
            ['Rabbit','Gracious, good friend, kind, sensitive, soft-spoken, amiable, elegant, reserved, cautious, artistic, thorough, tender, self-assured, shy, astute, compassionate, lucky, and flexible.  Can be moody, detached, superficial, self-indulgent, opportunistic, and stubborn.'],
            ['Dragon','Magnanimous, stately, vigorous, strong, self-assured, proud, noble, direct, dignified, eccentric, intellectual, fiery, passionate, decisive, pioneering, artistic, generous, and loyal.  Can be tactless, arrogant, imperious, tyrannical, demanding, intolerant, dogmatic, violent, impetuous, and brash.'],
            ['Snake','Deep thinker, wise, mystic, graceful, soft-spoken, sensual, creative, prudent, shrewd, elegant, cautious, responsible, calm, strong, constant, and purposeful.  Can be a loner, bad communicator, possessive, hedonistic, self-doubting, distrustful, mendacious, suffocating, and cold.'],
            ['Horse','Cheerful, popular, quick-witted, changeable, earthy, perceptive, talkative, agile, magnetic, intelligent, astute, flexible, and open-minded.  Can be fickle, arrogant, childish, anxious, rude, gullible, and stubborn.'],
            ['Goat','Righteous, sincere, sympathetic, mild-mannered, observant, artistic, intellectual, ingenious, innovative, creative, mothering, peaceful, and generous.  Can be indecisive, over-passive, worrier, pessimistic, sensitive, shy, and weak-willed.'],
            ['Monkey','Inventor, motivator, improviser, quick-witted, inquisitive, flexible, innovative, problem solver, self-assured, sociable, artistic, polite, dignified, competitive, objective, and factual.  Can be egotistical, vain, arrogant, selfish, reckless, snobbish, deceptive, manipulative, cunning, jealous, suspicious, and stubborn.'],
            ['Rooster','Acute, neat, meticulous, organized, self-assured, decisive, conservative, critical, perfectionist, alert, zealous, practical, scientific, and responsible.  Can be over zealous and critical, puritanical, egotistical, abrasive, proud, opinionated, and gives into empty bravado.'],
            ['Dog','Honest, intelligent, straightforward, loyal, sense of justice and fair play, attractive, amicable, unpretentious, sociable, open-minded, idealistic, moralistic, practical, affectionate, sensitive, and easy going.  Can be cynical, lazy, cold, judgmental, pessimistic, worrier, stubborn, and quarrelsome.'],
            ['Pig','Honest, gallant, sturdy, sociable, peace-loving, patient, loyal, hard-working, trusting, sincere, calm, understanding, thoughtful, scrupulous, passionate, and intelligent.  Can be naive, over-reliant, self-indulgent, gullible, fatalistic, and materialistic.']
        ];
        var y = parseInt(val("year"), 10),
            m = parseInt(val("month"), 10),
            d = parseInt(val("day"), 10),
            zod_offset = (y - 1924) % 12,
            n = new Date().getTime();
            t = new Date(y,m,d).getTime();
            age_in_ms = Math.floor(Math.floor( (n-t)/86400000 ) / 365.25);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "As a " + age_in_ms + " year old " + data[zod_offset][0] + ", you are " + data[zod_offset][1] + "</p>";

}
</script>
</body></html>
```